# Put the footer at the end of a min-height page

Tags: html, css

So I have a page with a min-height of 200vh and I would like to place my footer at the end at the of the second section at 200vh but when I try to use the position: absolute;bottom: 0; it puts my code at the bottom of my first 100vh section, any advices?
here is my snippet:

```css
html,body
{
min-height: 200vh;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

section
{
height: 100vh;
}

#first
{
 background-color: red;
}
   
#second
{
 background-color: black;
}

.is-bottom
{
position: absolute !important;
bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="first">
<!-- content -->
</section>

<section id="second">
  <footer class="is-bottom">
 <p>
      Hello, I'm a footer
 </p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Set `margin-top:-200vh`, it will stuck at bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give `position: relative` to your `body` element, or even better, to your `#second` section element, if you use `position: absolute` it tries to search a "parent" element with a `position: relative` in order to understand to which element your `bottom: 0` is referring to.

Comment: Or rather the second section element especially if there's going to be other stuff after it.

Comment: @radulfr yes, i'll add this to the answer